# In c++11, does dynamic_cast return nullptr or 0?

Tags: c++11, dynamic-cast, nullptr

I want to check the result of dynamic_cast.  In c++11 (or c++0x, for compilers that support nullptr), should I compare against nullptr or 0?

Does it matter, and if so, why?

Is the result compiler-dependent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both the constant `nullptr` (which is of type `nullptr_t`) and the constant `0` will implicitly convert to the null value of any pointer type. So comparing against either one will work and is technically OK. By the way, this means that `dynamic_cast` return neither one, it returns the null value for the particular pointer type.

It's probably best to get in the habit of using `nullptr` rather than `0`. As far as I know, it's only really necessary for proper overload resolution (e.g. one overload takes `int` and another takes `char*`). For consistency, avoiding `0` will be best.

**What do I mean by "the null value of a pointer type"?**

Consider a variable `char * ptr`. It's type is (unsurprisingly) `char *`. But the type of `nullptr` is the special type `nullptr_t`. So when we write something like `ptr = nullptr`, some technical things must happen

1. `nullptr` must be implicitly converted to `char *`.
2. The result of this conversion is set as the new value of `ptr`.

The null value for `char *` is the result of converting `nullptr` to `char *`. Conceptually, it's still `nullptr`, but with a different type (`char *`). This null value is distinct from the null value of `int *` or `string *` or any other pointer type. We tend to think of these null values as just `nullptr` (or `0`), but each one is really a distinct value from a different type. (By the way, the same conversion happens for comparison using `==`).

Although this may sound like nitpicking details, it's very important in overload resolution:

```
void foo(char * ptr) { ... }
void foo(int i) { ... }
void foo(nullptr_t ptr) { ... }

int main()
{
    foo(0); // Calls void foo(int), since 0 is an int
    foo(nullptr); // Calls void foo(nullptr_t), since nullptr is a nullptr_t
    foo(new char('c')); // Calls void foo(char *), since new char('c') is a char*
}
```

or when assigning unrelated null values:

```
char * c_ptr = nullptr; // Okay
int * i_ptr1 = nullptr; // Okay
int * i_ptr2 = c_ptr;   // COMPILER ERROR HERE
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the null value of a pointer type?  How is this different from 0 or nullptr?

Comment: @Patrick: Rather than answer this in a comment, I'll append it to my answer. I think it's relevant enough to the question.

Comment: Interesting.  So when I do `if (nullptr == dynamic_cast<foo*>(p))`, is `nullptr` first converted to the null value of `foo*`, and then the comparison is made?

Comment: In theory, the null value for a pointer could be something other than zeroed bits in memory.  But the integral value `0` and `nullptr` when converted to a pointer type must compare equal to the null value for a pointer type, and if you evaluate a pointer in a `bool`ean context the null value of the pointer type must evaluate as false, and non-null values as true.  Most environments store null pointers as a bunch of zero bits, however.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Evaluate the result in a boolean context:

```
Base * p = get();

if (Derived * q = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(p))
{
    q->derived_method();
}
else
{
    // *p isn't of type Derived
}
```

(This works in any version of C++.)

Comment: I like your solution, but Ken Wayne more directly answered my question, so I'm marking his as the answer.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This is probably the better form to use (even if `nullptr` always existed), since it works for more than just types that compare to `nullptr`. It works for any type which has a notion of emptiness, expressed as a conversion to `bool`, like `optional<T>` does. I also think it looks nicer for types like `std::function`, which are comparable to `nullptr`, but which aren't actually pointer types!