# In C++11, does a failed dynamic_cast return NULL or std::nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have the class hierarchy:

```
class Base{
}

class Derived : public Base{

}
```

Suppose I wish to check if an object is of type Derived or not :

```
Base* b = new Base();
Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b);
if(b!=nullptr){ //Should this check be for 0, NULL or nullptr ?
// b is not  Derived
}
```

Should I be testing for 0, NULL or nullptr in C++11 ?

Found an answer: (Sorry, it didn't show up when I searched via google)
[In c++11, does dynamic_cast return nullptr or 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590920/in-c11-does-dynamic-cast-return-nullptr-or-0?rq=1)

Comment: Regardless you should test for `nullptr` in order to communicate most clearly to readers of the code, which is what programming in a language above numerical machine code, is all about.

Comment: A failed `dynamic_cast<Base*>` doesn't return 0, NULL, or nullptr. It returns a null `Base*`. But that's irrelevant to the question of which of the 3 you should compare it with.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Then why do some people check for 0 when testing if a dynamic_cast worked ?

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `if(b)`? (And I corrected (I hope) the `dynamic_cast` to be `<Derived*>`, not `<Base*>`)

Comment: @John: Because a null pointer (of any type) can be compared to 0.

Comment: @KenY-N Yes, you are correct. I meant <Derived*>. I don't think if(b), makes sense because I was trying to understand how using a dynamic_cast I can determine if an object is a Derived class, given that it is a Base class or a descendant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C++11 §5.2.7/9**:

> **”** The value of a failed [dynamic] cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type.

Regardless, it's a good idea to use `nullptr` in order to communicate clearly to readers of the code.

Note that a failed `dynamic_cast` to reference type throws an exception, since there's no such thing as a null-reference.

---

In order to check if an object `o` of statically known polymorphic type `Base` is really a `Derived`, you can use a `dynamic_cast` directly in an `if` condition – there's no need to compare it explicitly to anything:

```
if( auto pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>( &o ) )
{
    // Use pd here
}
```

Comment: The part I don't understand is when they say "null pointer value of the required result type". What does that mean ? Shouldn't the null pointer value of any type by std::nullptr ? And why do people test for 0 then ?

Comment: @John: E.g. the null pointer value of required result type `int*`, is `static_cast<int*>( 0 )`.

Comment: Thats really confusing - but then  shouldn't the null pointer value of anything either be 0 or std::nullptr ? It seems to defeat the purpose of having std::nullptr..

Comment: But then what is they type of pd ?

Comment: In C++03 there was no `nullptr`. The literal `0` of any integral type converts implicitly to nullpointer of any pointer type. And so the nullpointer of any given pointer type, compares equal to literal `0`, because that literal `0` is promoted to the pointer type before the comparison. The resulting pointer nullvalue needs not have all bits zero. It can in principle have some nonzero bitpattern as value.

Comment: That makes sense now - I think the confusing bit is, it isn't immediately clear to someone like me what "null pointer value ... result type" means..