# What are the different nullptr types?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading this question :

[In c++11, does dynamic_cast return nullptr or 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590920/in-c11-does-dynamic-cast-return-nullptr-or-0)

I learned that the result of a dynamic_cast can be the null value for that particular type:

> Consider a variable char * ptr. It's type is (unsurprisingly) char *.
>   But the type of nullptr is the special type nullptr_t. So when we
>   write something like ptr = nullptr, some technical things must happen
>
> nullptr must be implicitly converted to char *. The result of this
>   conversion is set as the new value of ptr. The null value for char *
>   is the result of converting nullptr to char *. Conceptually, it's
>   still nullptr, but with a different type (char *). This null value is
>   distinct from the null value of int * or string * or any other pointer
>   type. We tend to think of these null values as just nullptr (or 0),
>   but each one is really a distinct value from a different type. (By the
>   way, the same conversion happens for comparison using ==).

So what are the different null pointer types ? Does it really matter ? Is it sufficient in any check (where we want to determine if something is null) to simply check if == to std::nullptr ?

Comment: `So what are the different null pointer types ?` doesn't make much sense because (as your quote tells you) it's any pointer type. All pointer types have null values.

Comment: `simply check if == to std::nullptr` Unless I missed something, types in C++ are not directly comparable with `==`. And a `char*` or `int*` is never the same as nullptr_t

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword, so it's not in the `std` namespace. Only its type, `std::nullptr_t` is in a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't different `nullptr` types. `nullptr` is a value of type `std::nullptr_t`. There are different pointer types, and any pointer type can have a null value, which when compared to `nullptr`, results in `true`. And the number of pointer types is infinite. Since you can form a pointer to any type, and the result is itself a type which you can form a pointer to. *(i.e. you can have `int*************************`)*

> Is it sufficient in any check (where we want to determine if something
>   is null) to simply check if == to std::nullptr ?

Not `std::nullptr`, just `nullptr`. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: So when we compare with nullptr, C++ checks if the pointer is a null pointer, but its not actually comparing it to a type ?

Comment: @John: Yes to the first, and I'm not quite sure what you mean by the second.

Comment: Well, if there are an infinite number of types, and we are doing an == comparison with nullptr, but at the same time nullptr is a keyword, and not a type, then we are not actually comparing with a type - we are checking if the object is equivalent conceptually to null. Is that correct ?

Comment: @John: Well, yeah. I suppose. But other than in template metaprogramming (which is executed at compile time), I don't think we are ever comparing with types. Runtime comparisons are always on values, not on types.

Answer (score 2):

> So what are the different null pointer types?

There is only one null pointer type, `nullptr_t`.

> Does it really matter?

Since there is only one type of null pointer, this question is moot.

> Is it sufficient in any check (where we want to determine if something is null) to simply check if == to `std::nullptr` ?

There is nothing like `std::nullptr`. `nullptr` is a keyword. *It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`*.

Yes, any pointer can be compared with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a type `std::nullptr_t`. It is not a pointer type. Despite this fact, we call an instance of this type (such as `nullptr`) a "null pointer constant".

For every type `T`, `T*` is a distinct pointer type, and there is a null pointer of this type.

There are suitable conversions from `nullptr_t` to any pointer type that allow us to use `nullptr` whenever we want a null pointer constant. e.g.

```
int *ptr = nullptr; // initialize to be the null pointer of type int*
```